# CSS split button with side drop down menu

Tags: html, css

I need a button with the following characteristics:

- User clicks the left portion - "Edit" of the button and it takes
  them to a form.
- User clicks the right portion and it has a drop down
  of a sub list menu.

I wrote the snippet below using two separate buttons which I took the approach from [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_button_split.asp) and it looks like what I want except:

- When I hover it, each button has its own hover behavior indepdently instead of doing it together.
- When I reside my browser, this button breaks up into different rows.

[image]

How can I fix these deficiencies? or better yet if there is an out of the box button like this? I tried to google "button with side menu", "button side dropdown", button sub menu" ect.. but no luck so far.

```css
.leftSideButton {
 box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 3px 0px #91b8b3;
 background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #68c6d0 5%, #55a2aa 100%);
 background-color:#64c1c9;
 border-radius:5px 2px 2px 5px;
 border:1px solid #566963;
 display:inline-block;
 cursor:pointer;
 color:#ffffff;
 font-family:Arial;
 font-size:15px;
 font-weight:bold;
 padding:11px 23px;
 text-decoration:none;
 text-shadow:0px -1px 0px #2b665e;
  
}
.leftSideButton:hover {
 background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #55a2aa 5%, #68c6d0 100%);
 background-color:#6c7c7c;
}
.leftSideButton:active {
 position:relative;
 top:1px;
}


.rightSideButton {
 box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 3px 0px #91b8b3;
 background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #68c6d0 5%, #55a2aa 100%);
 background-color:#64c1c9;
 border-radius:2px 5px 5px 2px;
 border:1px solid #566963;
 display:inline-block;
 cursor:pointer;
 color:#ffffff;
 font-family:Arial;
 font-size:15px;
 font-weight:bold;
 padding:11px 13px;
 text-decoration:none;
 text-shadow:0px -1px 0px #2b665e;
  margin-left: -4px;
}

.rightSideButton:hover {
 background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #55a2aa 5%, #68c6d0 100%);
 background-color:#6c7c7c;
}
.rightSideButton:active {
 position:relative;
 top:1px;
}
        
.splitButton{
    display: block;
}

.btn-group leftSideButton:hover {
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #55a2aa 5%, #68c6d0 100%);
 background-color:#6c7c7c;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="btn-group">
<button class="leftSideButton">Edit</button>
  <button class="rightSideButton">
<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
  </button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the hover to the parent div then apply the styles to both buttons.

```css
.leftSideButton {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 3px 0px #91b8b3;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #68c6d0 5%, #55a2aa 100%);
  background-color: #64c1c9;
  border-radius: 5px 2px 2px 5px;
  border: 1px solid #566963;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 11px 23px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px #2b665e;
}

.leftSideButton:active {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}

.rightSideButton {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 3px 0px #91b8b3;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #68c6d0 5%, #55a2aa 100%);
  background-color: #64c1c9;
  border-radius: 2px 5px 5px 2px;
  border: 1px solid #566963;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 11px 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px #2b665e;
  margin-left: -4px;
}

.rightSideButton:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #55a2aa 5%, #68c6d0 100%);
  background-color: #6c7c7c;
}

.rightSideButton:active {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}

.splitButton {
  display: block;
}


/* changes */

.btn-group {
  /* Shrink the parent to fit the content */
  display: inline-flex;
}

.btn-group:hover .rightSideButton,
.btn-group:hover .leftSideButton {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #55a2aa 5%, #68c6d0 100%);
  background-color: #6c7c7c;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="btn-group">
  <button class="leftSideButton">Edit</button>
  <button class="rightSideButton">
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Zohir, that definitely solves that hover issue but I guess the break up in line can't be help ? I look at the example in w3school and I see the same issue as well where the button component floats to next line when you resize the browser.

Comment: Oh i didn't fully read the requirements, i'll update the answer

Comment: You just change the display of the parent to `inline-flex` now the next issue will be a matter of preference, The viewport will shrink no matter what and it'll be up to you to chose from overflow, drop the arrow to the next line, or shrink the buttons.

Answer (score 1):

> When I hover it, each button has its own hover behavior indepdently instead of doing it together.

Remove `.btn-group leftSideButton:hover{...}` from your css.  You have already have this hover effect for each button declared previously.

> When I reside my browser, this button breaks up into different rows.

Add `.btn-group{ display: flex; flex-wrap: nowrap; }` to your css.